# Bourbon Neat is giving me error after sass watch

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

Hi guys i am new to Bourbon Neat. 
ive installed bourbon and neat in a folder.
Now after i do this

```
sass --watch scss
```

When it compiles the css generated has following errors.

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "... $grid-columns ": expected "}", was "!global !default;"
    on line 48 of C:/neatFinale/scss/../neat/functions/_private.scss
    from line 2 of C:/neatFinale/scss/../neat/_neat-helpers.scss
    from line 6 of C:/neatFinale/scss/../neat/_neat.scss
    from line 2 of C:/neatFinale/scss/main.scss
```

Please tell me if i am doing something wrong.
Thanks.
Ps: When doing `Neat--ver` it says `DL is deprecated.`

Comment: What version of Sass are you running?

Comment: Sass 3.3.4 Maptasticc Maple it says

Comment: Please show us the Sass which is generating the error - line 48 and environs.